# lag function on mysql

Tags: mysql, netezza

I've seen a few posts around this but didn't find one that quit met my needs. I want to be able to complete the following function in mysql database. I'm connecting via mysql workbench.

```
    SELECT dept_id,
    salary,
    month,
    LAG(salary,1,0) OVER(PARTITION BY dept_id ORDER BY month) lag_one,
    LAG(salary,2,0) OVER(PARTITION BY dept_id ORDER BY month) lag_two,
    LAG(salary,3,0) OVER(PARTITION BY dept_id ORDER BY month) lag_three,
    LAG(salary,4,0) OVER(PARTITION BY dept_id ORDER BY month) lag_four,
    LAG(salary,5,0) OVER(PARTITION BY dept_id ORDER BY month) lag_five
    FROM   Employees;
```

I need to do multiple lags not just skipping 1 row as I need to grab the last 5 historical records and assign a weighting to them.

sample data

```
 month, salary, dept_id
 1,2000,1
 2,2200,1
 3,2400,1
 4,2000,1
 5,2100,1
 6,2700,1
 7,2000,1
 8,2800,1
 9,2050,1
 10,2020,1
 11,2030,1
 12,2900,1
```

expected output

```
 1,2900,12,2030,2020,2050,2800,2000
```

Much appreciated

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected result. That would be much easier for us to answer you.

Comment: apologies i've added the suggestions

Comment: You output is still not clear that what do you want to achieve?

Comment: When I run the query at the top against the sample data I get the expected output in Netezza. In mysql, as I understand it no lag function exists? How can I achieve this without this function?